# http:/localhost:8000/mapTiles/OSM/{z}_{x}_{y}.png not working - SHINY R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, localhost, tiles

I'm working on a project with a shiny app running offline because I have to work in sewer systems. I managed to run my app with a batch file (converted in a `.exe` file since it looks more professional)

I did some test and I have encountered a problem with Leaflet and the tiles. It doesn't work offline. I tried many things to make it works offline :

- Loading the tiles in my working folder:

  ```
  setwd("C:/TestApp/data_hydrepat/tiles_hydrepat")
  center=getGeoCode("Paris") 
  for (zoom in 10:16) 
  {GetMapTiles(
  center, 
  zoom = zoom,
  nTiles = round(c(20,20)/(17-zoom)),
  tileDir="C:/TestApp/data_hydrepat/tiles_hydrepat/mapTiles/OSM/",
  urlBase= "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/",
  type = "osm") }
  ```

========================================================================

- Now that I have multiple png in the folder, I'm starting a serving working folder on port 8000 in demon mode.

  `deamon_id <- servr::httd(port = 8000, daemon = TRUE)`

========================================================================

- I'm trying to plot everything with those lines:

  ```
  tilesUrl <-"http:/localhost:8000/mapTiles/OSM/{z}_{x}_{y}.png" 
  m =leaflet::leaflet() %>%    
  addTiles( urlTemplate = "tilesUrl",option =
  tileOptions(tms = TRUE)) 
  m = m %>%
  leaflet::setView(2.351462,48.856697,zoom = 10) m = m %>%
  leaflet::addMarkers(2.351462,48.856697) 
  m
  servr::daemon_stop(which = daemon_list())
  ```

========================================================================

It doesnt work (only showing the marker at the right place but with a
grey background, you can try to write the below code with the default
tiles

````
```
m = leaflet::leaflet() %>%    addTiles() m = m %>% leaflet::setView(2.351462,48.856697,zoom = 10) m = m %>%
leaflet::addMarkers(2.351462,48.856697) 
m
```
````

========================================================================

Then I thought the problem was coming from the serving working folder. So I tried to launch only one png and it was working. So I think the problem is coming from: `{z}_{x}_{y}.png` But I'm not really sure. Does this line work on R Leaflet?  What could be the problem? I looked everywhere on google, couldn't find a solution. I'm trying to add every png as a unique tiles with this command.
https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/13645/could-anyone-explain-this-to-me-leaflet
Here is the only source I could find explaining the `{z}_{x}_{y}.png`

You can check for more details about what i try to achieve
 https://rdrr.io/rforge/RgoogleMaps/man/GetMapTiles.html

Can someone help me please ?

Best Regards, Anthony

Comment: The second answer in the link you gave explains it, the letters in ````{z}_{x}_{y}.png```` are placeholders. Leaflet uses javascript to replace those with numbers to fetch a tile.

Comment: Yes thank you, i managed to understand that.